# Windows Unix based client

Tags: windows, unix, client, cygwin

Is there any portable or light-weight unix base client available for windows? Though I know that with cygwin it is possible to execute unix based computing and commands for local machine, but I am wanting (if there's any) to have a light weight client that I can bring with me by a storage media. Is there anything like that available for windows?

Thanks.

Comment: Not too sure what you mean by "client" or even "UNIX-based", but you can definitely installed Cygwin on removable media.

Comment: I didn't understand what you actually want. Would ssh client do it?

Comment: Install WinSSHD and access your Windows machine using standard ssh client.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate some drive letter to a flash drive (say U:), then install [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) to it (installers: http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=2435&id=307402). Modify your PATH environment variable on both machines to point to the `bin` directories in both the MinGW and MSYS directories. Even if `PATH` entries are missing on a particular machine (because your flash drive isn't inserted), Windows will skip them.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you want a small set of UN*X utilities that you can execute on windows, more lightweight than cygwin.

[UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) is just that. It's a set of commands ported to windows from GNU source, packaged as .exe. The only dependencies are to ms CRT. Copy only the programs that you need.

[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) is similar and presumably more up-to-date, and is packaged as an installer.

Since you'll presumably be using a DOS shell, there are naturally some idiosyncrasies. In particular the `find` command is frustrating.